# Do good shocks have any oil below the top half?

Tags: oil, suspension, shock-absorber, lubrication, grease

Is oil below the top half of shocks indicative of failure, or is it supposed to be visible?

One repair tech said that any oil below the top half of a shock indicates failure.  Another repair tech said that oil below the top half is normal because it gets distributed along the lower half every time you go over a bump.

Which repair tech is correct?

Answer (score 3):

A shock absorber is supposed to be dry on the outside, leaking fluid (I suppose you mean that by grease?) is a sign of damage. The more hydraulic fluid a shock absorber looses the worse is it's capacity to dampen impulses.

I cannot indicate by what amount of leaking fluid a shock absorber is considered to be exhausted. Since the shock absorber is a highly important part of the suspension my personal strategy is it to replace them immediately if I see fluid leaking. When replacing them replace always both shocks on an axle.